# Track method flow with respect to threads in java.

Tags: java

Is it a way to track methods on a running JVM with thread details?

Like:

```
Method 1 -> Method 2 -> Method 3 -> Method 4 //called by Thread 1
Method 10 -> Method 20 -> Method 30 -> Method 40 //called by Thread 2
```

I want to see if there is a way to track like Thread 1 called `Method1, 2` etc? Where as Thread 2 called `Method 10,20` etc?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for but you can use `getStackTrace()` to get a list of methods (stack trace elements) currently run by a specific thread. eg: `someThread.getStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Runtime class to interact with java runtime environment. The java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime() method returns the runtime object associated with the current Java application.
With this object you can track these me.

public static void main(String[] args) {

// print when the program starts

System.out.println("Program starting...");

// get the current runtime assosiated with this process

Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

// print the current free memory for this runtime

System.out.println("" + run.freeMemory());
   }